# Magento 2 ACL rule move from one db to another

Tags: magento2.2, acl

I have two environment of my website using **Magento 2.2.1**
One is dev and another is staging.

I have created ACL Roles and assign them to users.

Now i want to copy these ACL Roles to staging environment.

I have exported 4 tables:

> admin_user, admin_passwords, authorization_role, authorization_rule

and import into staging db.

But am facing issue while doing setup:upgrade.

Issue is:

> We can't find the role for the user you wanted

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is flawed.

All you have to do is:

1. deploy the corresponding acl.xml files to staging and execute
2. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: I did that but am facing issue in Magento_Integration module: We can't find the role for the user you wanted

Comment: Seems like there is more to this than the information that you provide. Restoring the db to a previous working state might also help.

Comment: After restoring db to previous version its working fine but ACL role are not there.

Comment: Deploy code that contains your acl rules.
Acl rules are added in acl.xml files.
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean

Also the modules that hold your acl.xml files should be enabled for this to work.